# Is it possible to disable sorting in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My job dosn't require sorting, just aggregation information per key. So I think if it possible to disable sorting of all information in order of increasing performance.

---

Note: I can't set reducers count to zero because I need to aggregate data between many mappers. I just not interested in sorted result withing one reducer.

Comment: AFAIK, sorting is essential phase in MR job, you can not omit it. Sorting is usually not significant element of performance overhead.

Comment: yura, did you find a solution? I am voting to close as a dupe, because in the other question, there is actually an answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop and Python: Disable Sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188263/hadoop-and-python-disable-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main purpose to sort the map output is, when the  tuples reaches reducer, reducer has to make ) to invoke reducer task, with the sorted map output list it can make the list just by sequential scan (when it sees different key then just make new list), if the map output is not sorted then it has to scan the whole list to form the list with same key.

Answer (score 0):

No, Sorting in MapReduce is essentially performed for **internal purposes** and not for the end results to be sorted. 
Sorted input ensures good performance when creating list of values for unique keys, which are fed as Values> arguments when calling the reduce() function.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling and sorting in Hadoop MapReduce are not performed at all if you specify zero reducers (`setNumReduceTasks(0)`).
and 
The number of reducer can be set to 0 in driver class by `job.setNumreduceTasks(0)`.This shows that there is no reducer phase and has only map phase.It is called as a map-only job.