# Hadoop and Python: Disable Sorting

Tags: python, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I've realized that when running Hadoop with Python code, either the mapper or reducer (not sure which) is sorting my output before it's printed out by **reducer.py**.  Currently it seems to be sorted alphanumerically.  I am wondering if there is a way to completely disable this.  I would like the output of the program based off of the order in which it's printed from **mapper.py**.  I've found answers in Java but none for Python.  Would I need to modify **mapper.py** or perhaps the command line arguments?

Comment: If you need the output same way as its printed by mapper then why do you need reducer?

Answer (score 1):

You should read more on basic MapReduce concepts. Even though the sorting may be unnecessary in some cases, the shuffling part of the "Shuffle & Sort" phase is an intrinsic part of the MapReduce model. The MapReduce framework (Hadoop) needs to group the output of the mappers so that it sends all the keys together to one single reducer, so that the reducer can actually "reduce" the data. When using streaming, the key value pairs are--by default--separated by a tab value. From your sample code in other SO questions, I can see that you are not providing producing "key, value" tuples, but rather just single text lines.

EDIT: Added the following answer to the question "How to make it sort numerically (e.g., 9 before 10)?"

Alternative 1: Prepend zeroes to your keys so that they all have the same size. "09" comes before "10".

Alternative 2: Use the `KeyFieldBasedComparator`, as indicated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331722/how-to-sort-numerically-in-hadoops-shuffle-sort-phase).

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The program I'm writing, however, does not produce key value tuples.  Do you know how to disable the automatic sorting?

Comment: No, but my point is that even if you could disable the sorting, you cannot get rid of the shuffling by keys (your lines are being interpreted as keys by the framework), so the output would get mingled anyway. Perhaps you need a model different than MapReduce.

Comment: Is there a way to change the sorting so 9 will appear before 10?

Comment: Alternative 1: Prepend zeroes to your keys so that they all have the same size. "09" comes before "10".

Comment: Alternative 2: Use the `KeyFieldBasedComparator`, as indicated in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331722/how-to-sort-numerically-in-hadoops-shuffle-sort-phase).

Comment: The problem here is that the question states "disable sorting". I came here looking for that myself, as sorting is completely meaningless in my case: I am using the identity reducer MERELY to reduce the number of files in Hadoop FS (no pun intended). The sortiness of the output is completely irrelevant to me.
The answer as such appears to be "no", but I have not convinced myself why this needs to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, as stated <s>[here](http://www.prohadoopbook.com/forum/topics/how-to-disable-sort-in-hadoop)</s>:

> If your number of reduce tasks is not 0, the hadoop framework will sort your results. There is no way around it.

Comment: While the link is dead, "no" answers the question as titled. (@gsamaras, do you have a similar link that is still alive?)

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos I couldn't find one at a glance, if you have one, please share. Good thing I copied the essential information into the answer, since no link is immortal these days =)