# Hadoop V2: Turn off shuffling/sorting?

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I was wondering if there was any way to turn off shuffling/sorting in the Map phase of a job? My job doesn't require a Reduce phase so I don't need the shuffle and sort.

Im using hadoop version 2.2.0

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074910/is-it-possible-to-disable-sorting-in-hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setNumReduceTask to 0 which will just map the data without shuffling and sorting.

Comment: Thanks.

Just to help other people coming to the post. You set the number of reduce tasks to zero by calling ``yourJob.setNumReduceTask(0);`` in your main method of your MR job.

Comment: In effect, does this mean that each job will only access local data?  I'm trying to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31789176/320399).